# Nested cuboids using pre3d

Tags: javascript, debugging, webgl, 3d-rendering, pre-3d

Taking help of this [example](http://deanm.github.com/pre3d/colorscube.html) from [pre3d](https://github.com/deanm/pre3d) js lib, I am trying to create a cuboid container which will contain smaller cuboids inside.

Now, what I'm not getting properly, is how to place the internal cuboid in a predefined co-ordinate. What will be the generalized formula here for `transform2.translate`? This formula should work for any cuboid I want to place inside.

The following is what I've done till now. If you put this two files inside [demos](https://github.com/deanm/pre3d/tree/master/demos) directory, they should work instantly.

```
// experiment.js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var screen_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var renderer = new Pre3d.Renderer(screen_canvas);

  var transform1 = new Pre3d.Transform();
  transform1.translate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);

  var transform2 = new Pre3d.Transform();
// **** This is where i need your help ****//
  transform2.translate(10 - 10/2, 10 - 10/2 - 2, 10 - 10/2);
// **** **** **** ****//
  var cubes = [
  { //container
    shape: Pre3d.ShapeUtils.makeBox(10, 10, 10),
    color: new Pre3d.RGBA(9 / 10, 9 / 10, 9 / 10, 0.3),
    trans: transform1
  },
  { //axis
    shape: Pre3d.ShapeUtils.makeBox(10, 0.01, 0.01),
    color: new Pre3d.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    trans: transform1
  },
  {//axis
    shape: Pre3d.ShapeUtils.makeBox(0.01, 10, 0.01),
    color: new Pre3d.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    trans: transform1
  },
  {//axis
    shape: Pre3d.ShapeUtils.makeBox(0.01, 0.01, 10),
    color: new Pre3d.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    trans: transform1
  },
  {
    shape: Pre3d.ShapeUtils.makeBox(10.0, 2, 2),
    color: new Pre3d.RGBA(1.2, 0, 0, 0.3),
    trans: transform2
  }
];


  var num_cubes = cubes.length;
  var cur_white = false;  // Default to black background.

  function draw() {

    for (var i = 0; i < num_cubes; ++i) {
      cube = cubes[i];
      renderer.fill_rgba = cube.color;
      renderer.transform = cube.trans;
      renderer.bufferShape(cube.shape);
    }
    renderer.ctx.setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    renderer.drawBackground();

    renderer.drawBuffer();
    renderer.emptyBuffer();
  }

  renderer.camera.focal_length = 1.5;

  DemoUtils.autoCamera(renderer, 0, 0, -30, 0, 0, 0, draw);


  draw();
}, false);
```

Sample HTML goes here:

```
// experiment.html
<html>    
<head>    
<title>experiment Front end</title>    
<style>
  body * {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  body.white {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
  body.black {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  span.spaceyspan { margin-right: 20px; }
  div.centeredDiv { text-align: center; }
  li { list-style: none; }
  td { padding-right: 10px; }
</style>

<script src="../pre3d.js"></script>
<script src="../pre3d_shape_utils.js"></script>
<script src="demo_utils.js"></script>
<script src="experiment.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="centeredDiv">
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
  Sorry, this demo requires a web browser which supports HTML5 canvas!
</canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a concentric constraint to make this work. A concentric constraint makes two concentric geometries concentric with respect to each other. Here is the process:

- Find the center point of the outer cube
- Place the center point of the inner cube at the same point
- Repeat

**References**

- [Add a Concentric Constraint](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/files/WS73099cc142f4875546792d6511e39d97277-1aa7.htm)
- [Constraints 3D](http://download.novedge.com/brands/VX/Helps/doc/0116.htm)